# Audio amplifier for 600 ohm headphones

Tags: amplifier, audio, speakers

I am working on a design which must drive an audio output into 600 ohm headphones (aviation headsets). Normally, I would just use an off-the-shelf class D amplifier but I can only find ICs designed to drive 4-8 ohm loads. This could still work with an audio transformer, but would require a 75:1 winding ratio. The highest ratio I can find is ~55:1.

Can someone recommend a different design approach?

Comment: Mouser lists a bunch of audio amplifiers rated for 600 ohm loads.  How much power do you need?

Comment: Wow, I was only searching on Digikey. I normally assume that they have the same stuff as Mouser, but not in this case...

Comment: 600:8 ohm impedance ratio goes with square root: you need about 8:1 or 9:1 turns ratio.

Comment: @glen_geek Oh yeah, I forgot about that. It's been too long since circuits class. I think [this](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/tamura/MET-35/MT4153-ND/285670) is what I'm looking for

Comment: 1 milliWatt may suffice. Thus 1 volt RMS is a goal.

Comment: @glen_geek Please post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: My comment doesn't answer the question you've asked.  I've attempted an answer.

Comment: Just a mere comment but if you are only going to drive 600 ohm loads, the NE5532 opamp will do a great job, for smaller loads you'll need something like a couple of transistors at the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A transformer to make 600 ohm headphones appear as an 8-ohm load for the amplifier may be a bad idea...

Low-impedance headphones are ubiquitous. Plugging one into your transformer would present a load of very low impedance to the amplifier, which might dangerously overheat.

Most audio power amplifiers are designed for an 8-ohm load - some for 4 ohm, and a few for 2 ohm. Any of these won't complain if they see a load of 600 ohms. It is difficult to say if you'll get enough volume from your 'phones before distortion sets in.  Those 600 ohm 'phones might just give you adequate volume when driven directly - no transformer.
It comes down to Ampere-turns. Drive an 8-ohm speaker with the same voltage as 600 ohm headphones. The 8-ohm speaker gets more current through few turns. Headphones get much less current through many more turns. I have **4000 ohm** headphones that sound about as loud as **8-ohm** headphones when plugged into an amplifier designed for 8 ohms.
So just try any of the amplifiers that are designed for 8 ohm load.

Answer (score 0):

Linear or Class D Differential Drive with 100mW may hurt your ears.  How much power did you think you needed?

Start with specs 1st for Power, Radiated / conducted noise , spectrum , interface , etc. before you start ANY real design then choose make or buy.